# How to trigegr a "Share Dialog", using facebook SDK for Javascript?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

Here I have a very, very noob question. I'm trying to create a web facebook app, using Javascript SDK. I have never done any website, any app, etc. So very basic, excuse me in advance..

Basically, I'm following the steps decribed in the quickstart: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

I created a html file, and copy-pasted exactly what is described on this page:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
  appId      : 'your-app-id',
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.8'
});
FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I changed "your-app-id" with the id I was provided.

Then I just open my html file with my web browser, which is showing a blank page, I guess it's normal at that point.
Then, I go to the next step, that is supposed to "trigger a share dialog" (see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/examples). Again, I copy-paste the provided snipped starting with FB.UI(... and paste it after the FB.init() call, which is just before the "FB.AppEvents.logPageView();" line, if I'm not mistaken (?).

And then I reload my html file with my browser.
According to the "examples" page, "Now when you reload your page, you'll see a Share dialog appear over the top of the page."
Well, it's still a blank page.

So, I guess my approach is very naive.. is it supposed to work just like that? Or if not, what am I doing wrong? Am I supposed to download something before?

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to test this on a real server, not just by opening the html file in a browser. Either upload it to an external server or start one on localhost. You can also try adding the protocol:

```
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```

...but i would recommend using a server on localhost and NOT adding the protocol.